# What makes "Color-Safe Bleach" color safe?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, redox

The ability of bleach ($\ce{NaOCl}$) to change the color of garments and introduce "bleach stains" is a well-known issue. In this question:
[Does bleach turn a substance white or colorless?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18991/does-bleach-turn-a-substance-white-or-colorless?rq=1), the accepted answer says the mechanism is breaking apart long pigment compounds.

As per [Clorox's website](https://www.clorox.com/dr-laundry/the-difference-between-color-safe-and-non-color-safe-bleach/), Clorox2 color-safe bleach uses hydrogen peroxide ($\ce{H2O2}$) and:

> "[a]t the concentration used in the laundry, hydrogen peroxide is a much less aggressive bleach than sodium hypochlorite."

I'm trying to parse this ad-copy statement into GenChem vocabulary. Is the idea that while $\ce{H2O2}$ is also a powerful oxidizing agent, it isn't strong enough to disrupt the pigment molecules in dyes (like $\ce{NaOCl}$), but still powerful enough for general cleaning / stain removal? Or is it simply a result of having a diluted product?

Comment: afaik $\ce{H2O2}$ is not *that* powerful an oxidizing agent. It can sometimes act as an oxidizer and sometimes even as a reducing agent. I call it *double minded*. $\ce{NaOCl}$ on the other hand, *knows* that it'll act like an oxidizing agent.

Comment: @BerryHolmes good point, I suppose we aren't filling the washing machine with piranha solution lol